# Show and restore all deleted files between last backup and now?

Tags: finder, backup, time-machine

I accidentally deleted a couple of files and tried to restore them using Time Machine. However, Time Machine requires me to know at least some information about the files so I can perform a search using Finder.

Honestly, I have no idea which files I accidentally deleted.

Therefore I would like to compile a list of all files that have been deleted between the last successful backup and now to ultimately being able to restore them.

Does anyone know how I could achieve that?

Thanks!

Comment: An app BackupLoupe can show all the chnages between two TM backups.

Comment: Thanks! This one? https://www.soma-zone.com/BackupLoupe/

Comment: Yes that is the one - there is also a way to do this via command line tools but I don't know how

Comment: I am going to give it a try, thanks!